# Rename command - Key off of a digit or number

Tags: rename

I have additional rename command question.

I have files in the format:

```
Gauge50.jpg
Gauge51.jpg
DigitalGauge_01.jpg
DigitalGauge_02.jpg
etc.
```

What I want to do is target the Gauge50 and turn it into DigitalGauge_50.jpg, etc.

However, something simple like:

```
rename 's/Gauge/DigitalGauge_/' *.jpg
```

Will cause the other files already in the correct format to turn into:

```
DigitalDigitalGauge__01.jpg
DigitalDigitalGauge__02.jpg
```

So how can I use rename to target just the format Gauge##? (Characters-Digit-Digit)?  Thanks!

This [`rename` command](http://plasmasturm.org/code/rename/) was installed via [home-brew](http://brewformulas.org/rename) on a Mac.
Output of `rename -v`:

```
rename -v
Usage:
    rename [switches|transforms] [files]

    Switches:

    -0/--null (when reading from STDIN)
    -f/--force or -i/--interactive (proceed or prompt when overwriting)
Wide character in print at /System/Library/Perl/5.18/Pod/Text.pm line 286.

    -g/--glob (expand "*" etc. in filenames, useful in Windows™ CMD.EXE)
    -k/--backwards/--reverse-order
    -l/--symlink or -L/--hardlink
    -M/--use=*Module*
    -n/--just-print/--dry-run
    -N/--counter-format
    -p/--mkpath/--make-dirs
    --stdin/--no-stdin
    -t/--sort-time
    -T/--transcode=*encoding*
    -v/--verbose

    Transforms, applied sequentially:

    -a/--append=*str*
    -A/--prepend=*str*
    -c/--lower-case
    -C/--upper-case
    -d/--delete=*str*
    -D/--delete-all=*str*
    -e/--expr=*code*
    -P/--pipe=*cmd*
    -s/--subst *from* *to*
    -S/--subst-all *from* *to*
    -x/--remove-extension
    -X/--keep-extension
    -z/--sanitize
    --camelcase --urlesc --nows --rews --noctrl --nometa --trim (see manual)
```

Answer (score 0):

Once I posted this question - a related question popped up that helped me answer.

The format to use would be:

```
rename 's/Gauge([0-9])/DigitalGauge_$1/' *.jpg
```

This would do what I need it to do.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative is to just restrict the renaming to the `Gauge*` files, and keep the simple pattern:

```
rename 's/Gauge/DigitalGauge_/' Gauge*.jpg
```